# PostgreSQL vs. PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server Client Connectors

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, licensing

While comparing the [PostgresSQL and PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server future matrix](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server/features-comparison), I noticed that there is a difference at the client connector section. The community edition of PostgreSQL supports only libpq and ECPG. The PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server supports: libpq, ECPG, pgJDBC, psqlODBC, Npgsql(.NET), OCL(OCI). What does it mean for me if I want to use the JDBC client library to connect to the community edition of the PostgreSQL server? Do I need to buy a licence for PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server? I'm little bit confused ... could anyone explain it to me?

Cheers, Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to buy anything.

The "community" edition (which is actually a name invented by EnterpriseDB - there is no such thing really) can be used with the JDBC driver downloadable from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html without any problems